# evaluating what the haskell compiler is doing

Tags: haskell

I have these functions:

```
first_threes :: [Int]                     -- first three numbers repeated
first_threes = 1:2:3:first_threes         -- th.1

take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]                 -- take
take 0 _ = []                             -- t.1
take n (x:xs) = x : (take (n - 1) xs)     -- t.2

sum :: [Int] -> Int                       -- summation of an Int list
sum [] = 0                                -- s.1
sum (x:xs) = x + (sum xs)                 -- s.2
```

And I have to evaluate what is going on under the "bonnet" of the compiler in each step. So far I have this:

```
1.  my_sum (my_take 5 first_threes) =
2.  my_sum (my_take 5 (1:2:3:first_threes)) =
3.  my_sum (1:(my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes))) =
4.  1 + my_sum (my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes))=
5.  1 + my_sum (2:(my_take 3 (3:first_threes)))=
6.  1 + 2 + my_sum (my_take 3(3:first_threes))=
7.  1 + 2 + my_sum (3: (my_take 2([]:first_threes)))=
8.  1 + 2 + 3 + my_sum( my_take 1([]:first_threes))=
9.  1 + 2 + 3 + my_sum( my_take []([]:first_threes))=
```

Is this correct? I need to know as then I can evaluate what is going on in each step, but can't do this until I know I have done each step of what the compiler's doing correctly. Any hit would be really appreciated. Thanks x

Comment: It's going fine until step 7. `([]:first_threes)` is not even a well-type expression. `my_take 3(3:first_threes)` reduces simply to `3 : my_take 2 (first_threes)`. To continue evaluating `my_take` you have to evaluate `threes` like you did in step 2.

Comment: Thankyou @user2407038 for pointing me in the correct direction. x

Comment: `1. my_sum (my_take 5 first_threes) = 
    2. my_sum (my_take 5 (1:2:3:first_threes)) =
    3. my_sum (1:(my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes))) =
    4. 1 + my_sum (my_take 4 (2:3:first_threes))=
    5. 1 + my_sum (2:(my_take 3 (3:first_threes)))=
    6. 1 + 2 + my_sum (my_take 3(3:first_threes))=
    7. 1 + 2 + my_sum (3: (my_take 2(first_threes)))=`
So like this the it adds 1+2 +(the sum of 1+2) + the bracketed 3, then stops. Great stuff.

Comment: It certainly doesn't stop, because you can still reduce it - `threes = 1:2:3:threes`. The final evaluation should be a single number. Strictly speaking you can't reduce the `1 + 2` because the expression is actually `1 + (2 + (3 + ...)))`.